# Variable does not work with alsoResize: for colSelect

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable

I got this code, which works fine, until I change '.1' too colselect. I guess its because it gets the value too late and when I want to use colselect it haven't registered. Does anyone have any ideas on how to solve this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        var colSelect;
        
        $('.test2').mousedown( function(){      
            colSelect = '.' + $(this).attr('id');
        });
        
        $( '#1' ).resizable(
        {handles:'e'},
        {alsoResize: '.1'} // <- here I would like too change '.1' to colselect
        );
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var colSelect;

   $('#one').on('mouseover' ,mousedwn);

 function mousedwn(){
    colSelect = '.' + $(this).attr('id');
    resize(colSelect);

 }
$('#one').on('mouseout' ,function(){
    $('#one').off('mouseover' ,mousedwn); //prevent memory leaks
});


 });

function resize(para){

 $( '#1' ).resizable(
    {handles:'e'},
    {alsoResize: para} 
    );

 }
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ashish41191/wTamx/2/)

Comment: thanks for trying but that wont work. the '.1' work, that wasnt the issue

Comment: Are you try to do this - ` $('.test2').mousedown( function(){      
            colSelect = '.' + $(this).attr('id');
 $( '#1' ).resizable(
        {handles:'e'},
        {alsoResize: '.1'}  
        );`
        });

Comment: yes '.1' will work...Yes tried that, it almost works, the problem is, you have too first click one time too see the resize handlers and use it. Wich is not very good

Comment: Don't define your `.resizable()` on inside `.ready()` because this will initialize their all value when your `document` is `ready` so first make a function and then call it on mousedown with your `colSelect` as parameter   !

Comment: I appreciate your help, but it does not work. If I first click and then click again to resize it, it works. But I dont want to click twice

Comment: here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/wTamx/   ...as you notice, you first have to click on the top div to get the resize handlers, then you can start to resize